# SpringFox 404 issue

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, springfox

I'm using Spring boot 2.5.14 with SpringFox 2.8.0

```java
@Bean
    public Docket docket() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .apiInfo(apiInfo())
                .useDefaultResponseMessages(false)
                .directModelSubstitute(LocalDate.class, java.sql.Date.class)
                .directModelSubstitute(LocalDateTime.class, java.util.Date.class)
                .globalOperationParameters(asList(
                        header(EXAMPLE, "example")
                ))
                .securitySchemes(asList(oAuth()))
                .securityContexts(asList(securityContext()))
                .select()
                .paths(regex("/api/.*"))
                .build().protocols(newHashSet("http", "https"));
    }
```

SpringFox dependencies:

```
    implementation "io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:$springfoxSwaggerVersion"
    implementation "io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:$springfoxSwaggerVersion"
```

When I try to access /swagger-ui.html#/ I'm getting 404.

Keep in mind that I don't want to upgrade to SpringFox 3.0.

Comment: What Springfox dependencies do you have? Also keep in mind that Springfox 2.8.0 was released 3 years prior to Spring Boot 2.5.x. Compatibility issues are very likely, so not upgrading to Springfox 3.0 might not even be possible.

Comment: Added springfox dependencies to the post. I have another application using the exact same versions of Springboot and Springfox and everything is working fine.